# Child state not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a blackjack app, and I'm having trouble re-rendering hands after the initial hands. I'm trying to update my state in App.js and pass it to PlayerHand.js to be rendered, but the child component is not re rendering, even though a console.log shows that the state has been updated in App. Interestingly, if I hit ctrl-s in my text editor, PlayerHand.js will update, even if I haven't actually changed anything in the code.

App.js

```
function App() {

  const [lobbyState, updateLobbyState] = useState('');
  const [playerHand, updatePlayerHand] = useState([]);

//code that updates my state
  const hit = () => {
    socket.emit('hit', roomName, function(newCard){ hit
      console.log('old player hand is ' + playerHand);
      var newHand = playerHand;
      newHand.push(newCard);
      updatePlayerHand(newHand);
      console.log('new player hand is ' + playerHand); //this shows a different hand than the first print statement
    });
  }   

//renders initial hands; seems to be working, but included in case it's relevant
socket.on('initialHands', (data) => {
    updateRoomName(data.roomName);
    var newHand = data.playerHand;
    updatePlayerHand(newHand);
    updateOpponentHand(opponentHand.concat([data.opponentFirstCard, 'back'])); 
    updateLobbyState('started');
  })    
  

switch(lobbyState){
        case 'started':
          return (
            <div className="lobby">
              <OpponentHand opponentHand = {opponentHand}/>
              <PlayerHand playerHand = {playerHand} />
              {currentPlayer ? <PlayerActions 
              hit={hit}
              stand={stand}
              /> : <h1> Not your turn </h1>}
              
            </div>
        )
        case 'waiting':
          return (
            <Waiting />
          )
        default:
          return (
            <Home 
            createRoom={createRoom}
            joinRoom={joinRoom}
          />
          )
      }
```

PlayerHand.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import cards from './exports';
function PlayerHand (props){
    const [hand, updateHand] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        var newHand = props.playerHand;
        updateHand(newHand);
    }, [props.playerHand]);
    return (
        <div>
            {hand.map((card) => (<img src={cards[card]} alt="card" className="card"/>))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PlayerHand;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  const hit = () => {
    socket.emit('hit', roomName, function(newCard){ hit
      console.log('old player hand is ' + playerHand);
      var newHand = [ ...playerHand ]; // <----- ***** THIS *******
      newHand.push(newCard);
      updatePlayerHand(newHand);
      console.log('new player hand is ' + playerHand); //this shows a different hand than the first print statement
    });
  }
```

When you do `var newHand = playerHand` , you are actually never creating a new object, only a new reference.  `var newHand = [ ...playerHand ];` on the **other hand** (pun intended) does create a new object which causes state to change and a re-render.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did newHand =  [...playerHand, newCard] and it worked perfectly. Great pun too :) Wish I could upvote too, but I don't have enough reputation for that.

Comment: @RiceinPot another option that I like using a lot is `updatePlayerHand((state) => [...state, newCard])`.  This is beneficial when you are updating state inside a `useEffect` or `useCallback` hook as you don't need to add the current object state to decencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try `updatePlayerHand(playerHand.concat(newCard))`.

`concat` should be used instead of `push` with `setState`. I am not sure about `useState` hook though.

Comment: I tried using concat, but that was a whole other headache. Besides, I'm not modifying the state directly with push, so I **think** it should be fine.